# How can I make this Index script show more than 150 results in Blogger?

Tags: javascript, json, blogger

I have been using this script which was great but unfortunately it will only show the most recent 150 results even if I change the parameter and I have more that many posts.
I guess the best result would be to break it up with results A-M , N-Z but I don't know how to do that. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<div>
<ul id="postList12"></ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var startIndex = 1;
var maxResults = 999;
var allResults = [];
function sendQuery12()
{
var scpt = document.createElement("script");
scpt.src = "/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json&callback=processPostList12&start-index=" + startIndex + "&max-results=" + maxResults;
document.body.appendChild(scpt);
}

function printArrayResults(root)
{  
   //Sort Alphebetically
   allResults.sort(function(a, b){
        var a_string = a.children[0].textContent ;
        var b_string = b.children[0].textContent ;

 if(a_string < b_string) return -1;
 if(a_string > b_string) return 1;
 return 0;
   })

   var elmt = document.getElementById("postList12");
    for (index = 0; index < allResults.length; index++) {
         elmt.appendChild(allResults[index]);
    }
}

function processPostList12(root)
{    
  var elmt = document.getElementById("postList12");
   if (!elmt)
      return;

   var feed = root.feed;

   if (feed.entry.length > 0)
   {
      for (var i = 0; i < feed.entry.length; i++)
      {
         var entry = feed.entry[i];
         var title = entry.title.$t


     for (var j = 0; j < entry.link.length; j++)
     {
        if (entry.link[j].rel == "alternate")
        {
           var url = entry.link[j].href;
           if (url && url.length > 0 && title && title.length > 0)
           {
              var liE = document.createElement("li");
              var a1E = document.createElement("a");
              a1E.href = url;
              a1E.textContent = title;
              liE.appendChild(a1E);
              //elmt.appendChild(liE);
              allResults.push(liE);
           }
           break;
        }
     }
  }
  if (feed.entry.length >= maxResults)
  {
     startIndex += maxResults;
     sendQuery12();
  } else {
     printArrayResults();
  }
   }
}
sendQuery12();
</script>
```

Comment: Change `var maxResults= 999;` to `var maxResults= 150;`. This function contains a loop when it reaches the maximum value, Blogger has maximum value of listing the posts.

Comment: Thank you - that seems to have worked.